# Return status message to a page after posting in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm fairly new to ASP.Net but have used ASP Classic before.

I'm trying to figure out how to return a status message to my front-end page from a "code behind" page.

```
public partial class test: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private String msg;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        status.Text = msg;
    }

    protected void action(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msg = "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

When my page posts to itself I'm not able to see the msg I'm expecting in the status label of my front-end page.

I'm guessing this is because the Page_Load function is executing before my action is performed or something like that.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to achieve, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you hooked up your button click event (or similar) to your method? Need more info, how are you triggering the post back? How are you calling action(object sender, EventArgs e)?

Comment: A couple of stylistic things, I believe overriding the OnLoad/OnPreRender method is more efficient than using the event. It's a personal thing but if you look at the stack traces of the two wiring events gives your page a lot more hoops to jump through. Also "action" is a Method and so should be capitalised. Same with "test" Pages are classes and so should be capitalised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your text on [OnPreRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.onprerender(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of OnLoad. It fires after the event and should be used to do as much UI as possible.

```
public partial class test: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private String msg;
    protected void OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        status.Text = msg;
    }

    protected void action(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msg = "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Typically if you're running through a few events this is the best way to do it - you don't know which order the events will fire in so you want your message to be set at the end. However unless you need to do anything more complex why not just set it in the event itself and get rid of the private variable and extra method call?

```
public partial class test: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void action(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        status.Text = "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isPostBack)
    {
    status.Text = "First time on page";
    }
}

protected void action(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    status.Text = "Hello world!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this, it illustrates what I was trying to explain about why you may sometimes try and keep the Page_Load and Action approach instead of just updating in the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using Session assuming you have button or any other other control that causes postback and that triggers **action** function.

```
public partial class test: System.Web.UI.Page
{
   private String msg;

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!IsPostback)
       {
          Session["Message"] = null;
       }
       else
       {
          status.Text = Session["message"].ToString();
       }
   }

   protected void action(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       msg = "Hello world!";
       Session["message"] = msg;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't like this approach 1) It uses session for no benefit 2) it would require the user to reload the page to call the OnLoad event and so doesn't acutally solve the user's problem

Comment: Hello, I did a slight improvement. However, I believe you could also achieve what you want by using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void action(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Your Message');</script>");
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally not very helpful, and you shouldn't post code that doesn't work anyway.